# Android Studio - Can't Resolve Dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I've updated my android studio to v1.1.0 and since then i have a problem.

when i try to import for example this lib: `compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.10.2'` this error appears to me:

```
Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve: com.nispok:snackbar:2.10.2
```

I noticed that i cant import every custom library that recently uploaded to jcenter.

For example i can compile this lib:

`compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.2.3'`

because not updated recently. but i cant use this lib:

`compile 'com.github.chenupt.android:springindicator:1.0.1@aar'`

because updated recently. Can anyone help me plz?

Comment: Post your build.gradle files.

Comment: I've found the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've find the problem. When I've updated Android Studio, the IDE automatically checked offline mode, and that was the reason why i couldn't import new version of  libs :)